# How to print each array separately in multidimensional array in php

Tags: php

I have a multidimensional array

```
array:2 [▼
    "lamborghini" => array:1 [▼
        "cars" => array:5 [▼
          0 => "1"
          1 => "4"
          2 => "2"
          3 => "5"
          4 => "7"
        ]
      ]
    "ferrari" => array:1 [▼
        "cars" => array:1 [▼
          0 => "8"
        ]
      ]
    ]
```

I tried to achieve the possible output like this

```
Lamborghini
1 4 2 5 7

ferrari
8
```

I tried this method

```
foreach($cars as $car)
{
    foreach($car as $product)
    {
        for($i=0; $i<count($product); $i++)
        {
            echo $product[$i];
        }
    }
}
```

And output that I achieved is this

```
142578
```

Can anyone help me achieving the possible output? It  should also print the first array name. eg

```
lamborghini
1 4 2 5 7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$cars = [
    'lamborghini' => [
        'cars' => [1, 2, 3, 4],
    ],
    'ferrari' => [
        'cars' => [1],
    ],
];

foreach($cars as $make => $cars) {
    echo $make . "<br>";
    foreach($cars as $models) {
        echo implode(' ', $models) . "<br>";
    }
}
```

I don't know how you want to display the results but you can remove the `. <br>` tags.

Comment: I will take care of the result. Yess this is what I wanted  thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this instead

```
<?php 
foreach($car as $fer){
    foreach($cars as $lamb) {
      echo "Lamborghini: ".$lamb;
    }
   echo "Ferrari: ".$fer;
}
?>
```

This way it will loop first the lamb and then the ferrari next

Comment: What if other manufacturers kick-in, then I always have to change the foreach loop. I want one general method that would print the first array then second then third until there aren't arrays anymore

Comment: Also if you see that first it should give the name of the array `lamborghini` then print its elements

Answer (score 0):

This will get you desired output:

```
foreach($car as $car_k => $car)
{
 foreach($car as $product => $num_car)
 {
    echo $car_k. ':' .implode(',',$num_car);
    echo "<br/>"

 }
}
```